# How to query additional databases using cursor in Django Pytests

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am developing a Django app (**Django v3.2.10**, **pytest v7.0.1**, **pytest-django v4.5.2**) which uses cursor to perform raw queries to my secondary DB: **my_db2**, but when running tests, all the queries return empty results, like if they were running on parallel transactions.

My test file:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True, databases=['default', 'my_db2'])
class TestItems:
    def test_people(self):
      person1 = PeopleFactory()  # Adds 1 person to my_db2
      assert fetch_all_persons() == 1 # Fails Returns 0
```

My Factory:

```
class PeopleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    id = factory.Sequence(lambda x: x + 1)
    name = factory.Faker('first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = People
```

My function:

```
from django.db import connections


def fetch_all_persons():
      with connections['my_db2'].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Persons")
        return len(list(cursor.fetchall())):
```

[According documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#testing-transactions) `transaction=True` should prevent this issue, but it doesn't, does somebody know how to fix it?

Note.- Using the ORM is not an option, this is just a simplified example to represent the issue. The real queries used are way more complex.

Comment: What is `PeopleFactory`?

Comment: Just a [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) model factory to easily create instances of my models in tests.

Comment: The marker does its job just fine, the issue is rather on your side. E.g. `PeopleFactory` commits to wrong database etc. At least I cannot reproduce the issue locally; can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you specified which database should be used by factory?  IMHO, PeopleFactory is inserting into defult db and Your quere is using to 2nd db. What will happend when you will remove 'default' from test declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hoefling and @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz were right, I just needed to add the corresponding DB within the factories:

```
class PeopleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    id = factory.Sequence(lambda x: x + 1)
    name = factory.Faker('first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = People
        database = 'my_db2'
```

Thank you both.